# Step response of Power amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, power-amplifier

i have the parameters for this linear amplifier

Swell rate >52 V/µs

Bandwidth DC … 5 kHz

Power 3 × 30 kVA

rise time at nominal voltage (230 Vrms) is 5 µs.

and the transfer function is:
$$F(s)=e^{-0.00003s} × 5.5 × 10^{12}/(s^2+ 12*10^{9}*s +1.4*10^{12})$$

the question is how he get that TF

[image]

Comment: Maybe by using curve-fitting to the measured response?

Comment: You have a time delay. Looks like about \$30\:\mu\text{s}\$ to me. What does that tell you about the numerator? (And, perhaps, please fix your stated transfer function.)